# History Api: How to store a page

Tags: javascript, browser-history

To be specific i will give a live example:

http://www.shopcade.com/rodrigopires/lists/5415e86366a92f4f158b4848/funky-shoes

At this page when a product is clicked it opens a frame-like page. On this page you can navigate through products. But when you click the close button, you can always go back to list page.

I believe history api has been used, but i really don't understand how they stored whole page content through all navigation.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't implicit spam to that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very similar demo application explained here:

https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

It uses Ajax, which I suspect your example also uses.